# Android ListView Recycle Mechanism

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I was following the tutorial [here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html) to make a list of checkboxes, and my adapter looks like this:

```
private class ViewHolder{
    CheckBox name;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater settingInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = settingInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                CustomCheckbox theCheckbox = (CustomCheckbox) cb.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG,Integer.toString(position));

        });
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

}
```

There are about 15 entries on my screen when I started this view, but when I scroll down and select the 16th checkbox its position goes back to zero again, and the following entries accordingly become 1, 2 ,3.... etc. How do I implement the holder so that I can get the correct position number for each checkbox?

Thanks!!

Comment: you need to hold the positions of ones that were checked in a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView recycle view indeed you are defining click listener only when view is NOT recycled so when you click you have "old" listener still active

```
  if (convertView == null) {
        //here you have new view
        convertView = settingInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        //here you get recycled view
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    //you should put you code here after you retrieve your view (either new or recycled)
    holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            CustomCheckbox theCheckbox = (CustomCheckbox) cb.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                    "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG,Integer.toString(position));

    });
```